# Como criar uma função para somar em php e salvar no mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Boa tarde.

Primeiramente, quero criar uma função no PHP que sempre que executada adicione +1 no MySQL.

No meu MySQL vai ter uma coluna chamada numeros, sempre que a função por executada, ele ira remover o que tem nessa coluna e vai estar adicionando +1

Exemplo:

Tenho na minha coluna o número 67, ai eu executo a função e na coluna vai passar de 67 pra 68

Espero que tenham entendi kkk

abraço!

Comment: Bem vindo so StackOverflow em Português! Qual a sua dúvida exatamente? Dê uma olhada nesse link de [Como fazer uma boa pergunta?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para melhorar a pergunta para que ela tenha mais chance de ser respondida.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso direto no MySQL

Se você tiver uma tabela "numeros" e ela tiver um campo "numero", você pode primeiro adicionar um registro com o valor zero

```
INSERT INTO numeros (numero) values (0)
```

Desta forma, você criou um registro na tabela. Para sempre atualizar este registro, você pode fazer rodar o seguinte comando:

```
UPDATE numeros SET numero = numero + 1
```

Desta forma, ao rodar o UPDATE, sempre vai incrementar o campo número em mais 1.

Comment: a como faço para usar esse UPDATE?

$somar = 'UPDATE numeros SET numero = numero + 1';
$result = mysqli_query($conexao, $somar);

OBS: $conexao é o que está conectando o MySQL

Comment: Edit: criei uma nova tabela como você falou.